# button click calling a MVC Action Method with parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to call MVC actions with parameters

```
location.href = '<%: Url.Action("mAction", "mControl", "new {IDs='+selectedIDs+'}) %>';
```

or `location.href = '<%: Url.Action("mAction", "mControl", "new {IDs=123}) %>';`

I get error:

> CS1010: Newline in constant

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strange quotes before new

can you try

```
location.href = '<%: Url.Action("mAction", "mControl", new {IDs=123}) %>';
```